# Infragistics XamDataGrid Row Select/Deselect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics

I have two `XamDataGrid` when I select a row in `XamDataGrid` A and then select a row in `XamDataGrid B` then row selected in `XamDataGrid A` should be deselect and vice-versa.
Please guide me.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/tour for a guide of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectedItemsChanged`event to deselect the records in other grid. as below code:

```
XamDataGrid.SelectedItems.Records.Clear();
```

There is no **`default functions/method available to sync two grids selection`**.